# MsSql "group by" result table design

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert Result 1 to result 2. I can not get result2 using the pivot table.

**Result1**

[image]

***Result1 QUERY***

```
SELECT Country,City,Count(*) as "Count"
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country,City
```

**Result2**

[image]

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @ADyson Yes I tried. But I cant use this line. Do you know how to select all column ? `FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  `

Comment: In that case please edit the question to show us your attempt and explain what error / unexpected behaviour you get. We can't fix code which we cannot see.

Comment: @DenizOzogul As I mentioned, in future please **edit the question** if you have updates. Don't place code in comments. Thankyou. Incidentally I'm glad you got an answer to this.

Comment: I guess you should use report editor to achieve this, not as a Pivot query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this dynamic sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp([Country] VARCHAR(20),[City] VARCHAR(20),[Count] INT)
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 'Germany'    ,'Aachen'    ,1  UNION ALL
SELECT 'USA'        ,'Albuquerque',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'USA'        ,'Anchorage'     ,1  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Denmark'    ,'Arhus'         ,1  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Spain'      ,'Barcelone'  ,1

DECLARE @Colmn nvarchar(max),
        @Sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Colmn=STUFF((SELECT distinct ', '+QUOTENAME([Country]) FROM #Temp
                FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 

SET @Sql =' SELECT Cityynames ,'+ @Colmn +' FROM
(
SELECT  *,Country AS Countrynames,City AS Cityynames
FROM #Temp
)dt
PIVOT 
(
MAX([Count]) FOR [Country] IN ('+@Colmn+')
) AS Pvt'
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Comment: Did you tried running this Query, City names are in a country column, OP wants a separate Columns for City according to the image. This solution does not serve purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature of SQL other that `PIVOT` where, as you have discovered, you need to know the values up front.

This formatting is typically done in the output part of the system, such as your report engine.  SSRS for example can handle this nicely & out of the box.

You would need dynamic SQL to achieve this lower down in the stack.